# SQL Query to group dates and includes different dates in the aggregation

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with two columns, dates and number of searches in each date. What I want to do is group by the dates, and find the sum of number of searches for each date.
The trick is that for each group, I also want to include the number of searches for the date exactly the following week, and the number of searches for the date exactly the previous week.

So If I have

| Date | Searches |
| --- | --- |
| 2/3/2023 | 2 |
| 2/10/2023 | 4 |
| 2/17/2023 | 1 |
| 2/24/2023 | 5 |

I want the output for the *2/10/2023* and *2/17/2023* groups to be

| Date | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 2/10/2023 | 7 |
| 2/17/2023 | 10 |

How can I write a query for this?

Comment: So (i) all dates are exactly 7 days apart? (ii) could there be a hole in your data e.g. 2/3/2023 is followed by 2/17/2023 instead of 2/10/2023?

Comment: What db are you using? Please edit and add the appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming weekly rows

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Dates] date, [Searches] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Dates], [Searches])
VALUES
    ('2023-02-03 00:00:00', 2),
    ('2023-02-10 00:00:00', 4),
    ('2023-02-17 00:00:00', 1),
    ('2023-02-24 00:00:00', 5)
;


;with cte as (
    select dates 
        , searches 
        + lead(searches) over(order by dates) 
        + lag(searches) over(order by dates) as sum_searches
from table1)
select * from cte
 where sum_searches is not null;
```

| dates | sum_searches |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-02-10 | 7 |
| 2023-02-17 | 10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ws2J_Rwq)